# Rails - db logic, scope data by company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have 3 models: `User`, `Receipt` and `Article`.

Only association is: Receipt `has_many` Articles.

Now I need 4. model, which is `Company`. User belongs_to company, and Company has_many Users.

User needs to see only Receipts and Articles that are in his Company. 
Do I need to have company_id in User, Receipts and Articles and browse by that id, or there is a better way?

Comment: Yes, you need to associate `Receipt` and `User` models with `Company` by having a `company_id` on their tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> User needs to see only Receipts and Articles that are in his Company

Tweak your associations like so

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end

#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :receipts
  has_many :articles, through: :receipts
end

#app/models/receipt.rb
class Receipt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :articles
end

#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :receipt
end
```

Now you can call `@user.company.receipts` and `@user.company.articles`

> Do I need to have company_id in User, Receipts and Articles and browse
>   by that id

With the above approach, you need have `company_id` in `users` and `receipts`.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to have company_id in User unless you are going with multitenancy. And you will also need to have company_id in Receipts but not in Article as it is already associated with the Receipt.
To access receipts you just need to do `user.company.receipts`

Answer (score 0):

**Create Relationship between two table**

```
class Receipt < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :receipts
end
```

Get the Record in simple way using that the relationship in model

ex: user.company.receipt.first.article